# JS not responding to updated txt file

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Aim:**

1. The background loop will continuously read and print the file (word.txt)
2. Pressing one of the buttons will overwrite the value in `word.txt`
3. This change will then be read by the background loop and printed

**What happens:**

1. The background loop continuously reads and prints the file (word.txt)
2. Pressing one of the buttons overwrites the value in `word.txt`
   but.... 3. This change isn't reflected in JS until I go on to the "word.txt" file in a different browser and refresh the page. Once this is done, JS starts recognizing it.

Any ideas? Sorry the snippet doesn't work as it has `php` in

```js
var instanse = false;
var state;
var mes;
var file;

console.log('update.js loaded');

function triggerUpdate(){
    console.log('update.js is triggered');
    updateChat();
}

//Background Loop
function updateChat(){
            var file = 'word.txt';
            var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
                {
                    if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                    {
                        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                        console.log(allText);
                    }
                }
            }
            rawFile.send(null);
    setTimeout(updateChat, 1500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Random Word Generator</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="update.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="triggerUpdate();">

    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="word"
                class="button" value="Button1" id="button1"/> 
          
        <input type="submit" name="word"
                class="button" value="Button2" id="button2"/> 
    </form>
    
    <?php
    //This function gets called when button is pushed
    function postword(){
        $fp = fopen('word.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $_POST['word']);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    //When the button is pushed, the function will be called
    if (isset($_POST['word'])) {
        postword();
        return;
    }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't mention nodeJS as tag?

Comment: @MisterJojo - its not Node. Just client JS and server php.

Comment: Sounds like your browser may be caching since using a new one works. Try adding a random number to the file - such as `var file = 'word.txt?v=' + Date.now() ;`

Comment: @cyberwombat - That worked perfectly, thanks! :D 
edit: never mind, I googled ?v= I'll have to remember this!

Comment: Cool. Added as a longer answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is caching the initial result of the `XMLHttpRequest` call. The easiest workaround is to fool the cache by appending a random number as a parameter to the url. it will get ignored by the filesystem when looking for the file.

You can add any query variable you want ('v' is popular - sort of stands for version).

There are many ways to get a random number but using the Unix timestamp - [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) 
- is an easy one that should do the trick in this case.

Change code from:

```
var file = 'word.txt';
```

To:

```
var file = 'word.txt?v=' + Date.now();
```

This which will create a call to a url like this: `word.txt?v=1519211809934`